# How to add string to stringstream?

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

I need to merge a lot of strings into one.
Something like this

```cpp
stringstream ss;
string str_one = "hello ";
string str_two = "world!\n";
ss.add(str_one);
ss.add(str_two);


string result = ss.str();
```

but there is no `add` function into `stringstream`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/basic_stringstream) has [`operator<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) overload to insert data into the stream. It would return a reference to the stream itself so you can chain multiple insertions.

```
ss << str_one << str_two;
std::cout << ss.str(); // hello world!
```

As an alternate, you can leverage [fold expression(since C++17)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) to concatenate multiple strings.

```
template<typename ...T>
std::string concat(T... first){
    return ((first+ ", ") + ...);
}

int main(){
std::string a = "abc", b = "def", c = "ghi", d = "jkl";
std::cout << concat(a, b, c, d); // abc, def, ghi, 
}
```

The fold expression is expanded as below:

```
"abc" + ("def" + ("ghi" + "jkl"));
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/7e4E8Pc1r)

Answer (score 3):

Very simple, all you have to do:

```
ss << " appended string";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str()` method like this:

```
std::string d{};
std::stringstream ss;
ss.str("hello this");

while(std::getline(ss, d)){
    std::cout << d;
};
```